# Can I use a custom hostname for Azure Event grid Topic

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure Event Grid topic:

```
https://xxx.westeurope-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events
```

Is there any way to direct clients to publish events to https://xxx.mydomain.com/api/events without getting certificate validation errors, etc.?

Comment: Currently there's no way to change that URL. At least it's not [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear, after researching further documentation and speaking to Microsoft that this is currently not possible.  If you create a CNAME entry in your own DNS to point to the Azure fqdn of the endpoint, certificate errors are (understandably) generated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some type of API gateway to accomplish this. The gateway would have your desired domain name and route for the public to submit requests. A service 
 behind the gateway would forward the request to the event topic's endpoint.

Another option, but based on the same idea mentioned above, would be to use Azure Functions. The function becomes the gateway and the client publishes to the function's endpoint. Code within the Azure Function bundles the request and forwards it to the event topic.

I'm currently using the Functions approach. My function accepts a generic JSON body, validates a few things, packages it up so it has everything the event topic needs (access keys, headers, correct properties for the event schema, etc), and sends it off to the event topic endpoint. If everything works, I send the client a 200 HTTP status from the Azure Function. If there's a problem, I send a 400 or 500 series status as appropriate.